# roscd does not return a specific workspace after sourcing setup.bash

Tags: ros, devel, ros-indigo, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I run ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04, and I have my catkin_ws in a given path. Everything worked perfectly until yesterday.
However, yesterday I tried to set up the Matlab engine to see if it was compatible with ROS. I got some errors for some reasons, but I don't care right now. What bothers me is that now I cannot change directory on my catkin_ws anymore, through `roscd`, because the command redirects me to `/opt/ros/indigo`. Obviously, I tried to source both the corresponding `devel/setup.bash` again, and my `~/.bashrc` after inserting the source command inside, None of the solutions worked.

So, I tried to create a second workspace, say `test_catkin_ws`, and after building it I sourced its `devel/setup.bash`. This time `roscd` command correctly worked and successfully redirected to `test_catkin_ws/devel`. However, If I try to source again the first workspace, `roscd` command wrongly redirects me to `test_catkin_ws/devel`. So, it seems that the `setup.bash` does not work for the first workspace, and the system redirects to the last workspace correctly sourced.

If useful, I show here the output of `printenv | grep -i ros`:

> ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/indigo/share/ros
> ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/src:/opt/ros/indigo/share:/opt/ros/indigo/stacks:/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/catkin_ws/src
> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
> OLDPWD=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/catkin_ws
> LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/devel/lib:/opt/ros/indigo/lib:/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/catkin_ws/devel/lib
> CPATH=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/devel/include:/opt/ros/indigo/include
> PATH=/opt/ros/indigo/bin:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2012b:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
> PWD=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/devel
> ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp:/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/catkin_ws/devel/share/common-lisp
> ROS_DISTRO=indigo
> PYTHONPATH=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/devel/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/indigo/lib/pkgconfig
> CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/test_catkin_ws/devel:/opt/ros/indigo:/home/marcofe1404/Documents/Software/ROS/catkin_ws/devel
> ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/indigo/etc/ros

Thank you in advance for whoever can help me to solve this issue.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253977/roscd-does-not-return-a-specific-workspace-after-sourcing-setup.bash/) by [marcofe](https://answers.ros.org/users/25343/marcofe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2017-02-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-02-07**:
Have you tried to delete the devel folder in the first workspace and redo catkin_make?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try the following and see if it improves your situation:

1. remove all `source ..` lines that you added from your `.bashrc`
2. delete the `build` and `devel` folder from your first workspace (ignore your second one for now)
3. in a new terminal, `source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash`
4. run `catkin_make` (or `catkin build`, whichever you prefer)
5. `source devel/setup.bash`

Now see whether you end up in the correct location.

The setup files are not magic, they basically just set some environment variables, and depending on what you `source`d before, those variables could / may include additional paths.

By rebuilding your workspace you regenerate a fresh set of `setup.*` files, which, if you followed the proper procedure, should work correctly.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-02-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [marcofe](https://answers.ros.org/users/25343/marcofe/) on 2017-02-07**:
I had done all of these steps before, but now following your instructions in your order works. Probably I was forgetting to source `/opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash` before running catkin_make. Thank you so much!