# Sourcing workspace not working

Tags: catkin, overlay

Something seems broken with sourcing workspaces on my machine. This previously worked but seems broken of it's own accord..

OS `Ubuntu 22`

Building with catkin tools

Before

```
printenv | grep ROS_PACKAGE
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/dev/ros1/share
```

Clean to be sure

```
catkin clean --yes
```

Source underlay

```
source /opt/dev/ros1/setup.bash
```

Build it

```
$ catkin build
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:        [explicit] /opt/dev/ros1
Workspace:                   /home/bearrito/dev
```

Compiles fine

Source

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

ROS Package Path not being set correctly.

```
printenv | grep ROS_PACKAGE
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/dev/ros1/share
```

`ROSCD` also takes me to the underlay not my overlay.

This is happening even if I create a new workspace and `catkin init` in that one.

Very similar to - [roscd does not return a specific workspace after sourcing setup.bash](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/78805/roscd-does-not-return-a-specific-workspace-after-sourcing-setup-bash). However those steps don't work for me.